Double multi-encryption?
Just noticed we’ve got two alike tags:

multiple-encryption
Multiple encryption means encrypting a message two or more times using either the same, or a different algorithm.
double-encryption
Double encryption is the process of encrypting a message multiple times, either using the same or a different algorithm.

Both practically describe the same.
Because “double encryption” seems to be one of many forms of “multiple encryption”, I would like to suggest making double-encryption a tag synonym of multiple-encryption.
As you’ll notice, double-encryption is merely used by this question. Meaning: we could also simply replace that double-encryption tag and let the tag fade out, but chances are that someone else will come along and use that tag again… so I guess making it a synonym of the multi-encryption tag could be the smarter move. What do you think?

Well, arguably the tag excerpt is wrong, since double encryption means.. double encryption. As in 'twice'. But I agree, double-encryption is too specific as a tag IMHO.

@Thomas Yep, that tag description isn’t the best. Whatever… the way I interpret things is that double-encryption is indeed encrypting it twice – aka “more than once”, which would also make it fit the multiple-encryption tag from the more-than-once perspective. Yet, I’m not saying I’m seeing things correctly in this case, that’s why I’ve thrown it in here for discussion. ;)

What's wrong if both of the tags exist? Does same meaning tags create any problem?

It looks like this has to be done by a moderator, since there are not enough users to vote on it.

@Giliweed There’s no actual “problem”. It’s more of a keeping-things-clean thing, as [tag:double-encryption] is somewhat redundant due to the existence of [tag:multiple-encryption].

I removed double-encryption from the one in question. If it ends up popping up again in the future, we can consider blacklisting it.
